Error using Electron's ipcRenderer on a ReactJS app with Socket.IO
I have a scenario with a Electron Forge application together with ReactJS and Socket.IO:
preload.js:
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron";

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
  };

  for (const type of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type]);
  }
});

let state = {
  config: {},
  store: {},
};

// Function to update the state
const updater = (key, value) => {
  state[key] = value;

  ipcRenderer.send("updater", {
    key: key,
    value: value,
  });
};

const URL = `ws://localhost:3010`; // Test port

const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io(URL);

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("Connect...");
});

socket.on("upload", (msg) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(msg);
  let key = json.key;
  let value = json.value; 

  if (key == "config") updater("config", value);
  if (key == "store") updater("store", value);
});

ipcRenderer.on('command', (payload) => {
  socket.emit("command", JSON.stringify(payload));
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("stateAPI", {
  state: state,
  updater: updater, // Expose the update function
});

main.js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      webSecurity: false, // Need this to use Socket.io? Is there other way to do it?
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // if embedded Linux set fullscreen
  if (process.arch.includes("arm")) {
    mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
  }

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", function () {
    console.log("-----> activate");
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  console.log("-----> window-all-closed");
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

process.on("uncaughtException", (error) => {
  console.error("Uncaught Exception:", error);
  fs.writeFileSync(
    "/home/torizon/app/error.log",
    `Uncaught Exception: ${error.message}\n${error.stack}`
  );
});

My react code: index.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron"; **<=== This is causing the error**


const command = (payload) => {
  ipcRenderer.send("command", payload);
};

const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(window.stateAPI.state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStateUpdate = (key, value) => {
      let clone = Object.assign({}, state);
      clone[key] = value;
      setState(clone);
    };

    ipcRenderer.on("state_update", handleStateUpdate);

    // Clean up the listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener("state_update", handleStateUpdate);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{state.config}</h1>
      <h1>{state.store}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => command("Test")}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

The webpack configuration: webpack.main.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
};

And webpack.renderer.config.js
const rules = require("./webpack.rules");

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "style-loader",
      options: {
        esModule: false,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        esModule: false,
        modules: {},
      },
    },
  ],
});
rules.push({
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i, // Add support for image formats
  type: 'asset/resource', // This will emit a separate file for the image
});

module.exports = {
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules,
  },
};

When I try to import ipcRenderer inside my ReactJs application I'm getting the following error:
index.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:1:1)
    at eval (index.js:1:1)
    at ./node_modules/electron/index.js (index.js:62:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:8878:32)
    at fn (index.js:9073:21)
    at eval (index.js:7:66)
    at ./src/components/home/index.js (index.js:945:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:8878:32)
    at fn (index.js:9073:21)
    at eval (app.jsx:5:74)

If I uncomment, there is no error but I cannot change state data between Electron and my application.
What can be causing this problem and how to solve it?

There are at least two problems with your code.
First, you get this error because you try to compile Node.js code (i.e. electron here by importing ipcRenderer) with webpack, and that it is not configured for it (see the target configuration of webpack). But it doesn't mean you should change its configuration. You React code is on the renderer process, and for security reasons, you should not use Node.js on this process.
To solve this first issue, you need to use your preload file to expose what you need (only what you need, not the whole IPC API). You can find plenty of examples on the official IPC documentation and the other docs I linked here.
Once you solved that, you may get a module not found error on your preload file. By default, and still for security reasons, preload scripts are sandboxed, it means you can only import a specific subset of Electron and Node's built-in modules on it. If you want to import socket.io-client and follow security recommandations, you need to do it on your main process.
